# How to make a game like Panda Mania in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I m new to this forum and in cocos2d world. I want to make a game like Panda Mania, in which I have to use swipe/fick to fire an arrow with force and gravity involve. I need some guideline how to progress in gaming world and what is the best option for achieving swipe/flick in iphone, should i use cocos2d or box2d for it.

Regards

Comment: break down your question into smaller ones also visit http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: how to swipe/flick can be implemented in cocos2d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anam, like Ali mentioned, you are asking many things at once.

In general you can look for examples and see how things are done and go from there. A good page is www.raywenderlich.com 
Also Cocos2D brings a good amount of examples that you can benefit from.

This tutorial comes to mind with your post: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14302/how-to-make-a-game-like-fruit-ninja-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-1

On the other hand, Cocos2D Vs Box2D may be a misdirected question because Box2D's main goal is to be a physics engine, not a general game engine like Cocos2d.
Depending on the game you can use them together, or use Cocos2D with Chipmunk or something else.

But many of the tutorials in Wenderlich's site will make this much more clear.